# queuing multiple encodings with different edits

Tags: premiere

Is there a way to queue multiple encodings with each being a different edit of my video?

For example:
I want to queue up 2 encodings.

1. is for youtube
2. is for instagram

I need to disable certain tracks on each. So, is there a way for me to disable those certain tracks for 1 and then queue that up? Then do the same thing for 2 and then queue it up? So, they are both building at the same time but with certain tracks enabled and disabled?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is just duplicating my timeline, make one for each type of encoding I want (clip_001_youtube, clip_001_instagram,...), then use Media Encoder, just publish them all and then let ME do it's thing of batching them.

I find it helpful to make a bunch of timelines that are almost the same. Sometimes, I use nesting to make it easier also.